# Input text field with event in javascript and auto fill value in target element

Tags: javascript, jquery

> I have a problem in targetting the last th tag.In the fifth th, i put
>   input type text.How to add event in this text field and the value of
>   the last th(ave) should be updated automatically?Any help here  is
>   much appreciated.

```
<tr>                 
  <th colspan="3">Learning Areas</th>
  <th colspan="2">Term 1</th>
  <th colspan="2">Term 2</th>
  <th colspan="2">Term 3</th>
  <th colspan="2">Term 4</th>
  <th>Ave</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($card['AllGrade'] as $subject)
             {!! Form::hidden('grade_id[]',$subject['grade_id']) !!} 
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">{!! $subject->subject !!}</th>
        <th colspan="2">{!! $subject->term_1 !!}</th>
        <th colspan="2">{!! $subject->term_2 !!}</th>
        <th colspan="2">{!! $subject->term_3 !!}</th>
        <th colspan="2"><input text="term_4" value="{!! $subject->term_4 !!}" 
              class="form-control" name="term_4"></th>

        <th colspan="2" name ="ave" id ="ave" value=""> total</th>


        </tr>
@endforeach


<script type="text/javascript">
$("tbody tr").each(function() {
    var total = 0;
    var ave = 0;
    var count = 1;
   $(this).children('th').not(':first').not(':last').each(function () {
    //"this" is the current element in the loop
    var number = ($(this).children('input').length == 0) ? $(this).html() : 
   $(this).children('input').first().val();
    total += parseInt(number);
    ave = total/count;
    count++;
});
    $(this).children('th').last().html(ave);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you include rendered `html` at Question?

Comment: please can you be more specific? what is your expected result? what exactly does not work? I tried it here and everything works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: sample table:  Math   80  85 81  87     Total ave.After the inputting 87 and upon keyup the value of ave should be automatically change.How would i do that Sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first.
I don't know if there is a reason why you chose `th`, but the ones inside `tbody` should better be `td` like :

```
<td colspan="3">{!! $subject->subject !!}</td>
```

and later you can change this line from this

```
$(this).children('th').not(':first').not(':last').each(function () {
```

to

```
$(this).children('td').not(':first').not(':last').each(function () {
```

And now the last part

```js
 function calculateAve() {
var aveValues = 0;
  $("tbody tr").each(function() {
    var total = 0;
    var ave = 0;
    var count = 1;
    $(this).children('td').not(':first').not(':last').each(function () {
    //"this" is the current element in the loop
    var number = ($(this).children('input').length == 0) ? $(this).html() : $(this).children('input').first().val();
    total += parseInt(number);
    ave = total/count;
    count++;
  });
    $(this).children('td').last().html(ave);
    aveValues = aveValues+ave;
  });
    $('#totalAve').html(aveValues/2);

}
calculateAve();
$('#myTable').on('keyup', 'input', function(){
 calculateAve();
});
```

```css
table#myTable th {
    background: #8BC34A;
    color: #fff;
}
table#myTable, table#myTable td, table#myTable th {
    border: solid #efefef;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table id="myTable">
  <thead>
   <tr>                 
    <th colspan="3">Subject</th>
    <th colspan="2">Term 1</th>
    <th colspan="2">Term 2</th>
    <th colspan="2">Term 3</th>
    <th colspan="2">Term 4</th>
    <th>Ave</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Math</td>
    <td colspan="2">81</td>
    <td colspan="2">87</td>
    <td colspan="2">81</td>
    <td colspan="2"><input text="term_4" value="80" class="form-control" name="term_4"></td>
    <td colspan="2" name ="ave" id ="ave" value=""> total</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Science</td>
    <td colspan="2">89</td>
    <td colspan="2">83</td>
    <td colspan="2">81</td>
    <td colspan="2"><input text="term_4" value="80" class="form-control" name="term_4"></td>
    <td colspan="2" name ="ave" id ="ave" value=""> total</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="11">Total Average</td>
    <td id="totalAve" colspan="2"></td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Sir Ruz, i use what you had suggested but the keyup didn't work.The value of ave did not change. What eq(4) input is for?

Comment: I put alert inside keyup but it seems it didn't  work because it generate Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

Comment: I'd change the version of jquery and now I've found out that it did not get the value of input.Instead of the values of td+td+td+td/4,the code only gets the td+td+td/4.So lacking value of the 4th td or no input included.

Comment: Update(but cannot make any changes to the Ave if user changes his/her input the second time arround):if('.form-control'){
        $(this).on('keyup', 'td:eq( 4 ) input', function(){
             $('.form-control').on("input", function() {
                var dInput = this.value;
                total += parseInt(dInput);

                 ave = total/count-1; 

             });

           console.log(ave);
          $(this).parent().next().html(ave);

     });
    }   
    
      $(this).children('td').last().html(ave);

Comment: Ok, now I get it. :) I will look and get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: Look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RuzgarDogu/4bjd3c9c/1/). It is working as expected.

Comment: Sir the second  value of the ave wont update  if i change the value of term 4.

Comment: Since you haven't provided an HTML output, i had no no opinion about your second term. So this code is not enough. So i will look at it and get back to you.

Comment: Sir this link was to my other post(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530324/input-text-field-with-event-in-javascript-and-auto-fill-value-in-target-element).It has been answered also.Thank you so much.Your effort means a lot to me since your answer was useful.It all started with your answer actually and it develops through the helps of others.

Comment: Saw the second fiddle,its really neat the  way you did it.That was what i am looking for.In my other post,Id ask also to put the Total average below the Ave column.Its just an additional requirement for a school card.Hope you could add it too.It might be useful to others in the future.

Comment: Oh I see..I'd run the snippet.Amazing..Thank you for this and hope many students/developers can make use out of it.I wish i could up vote your answer but my status here is too low.

Comment: Actually what you call `my other post` is this very post. You know it right? And this is the answer you asked for. But you did not even accept the answer. I don't know if you know how this site works, but if you want other people to benefit from a question/answer, you need to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark. And it has nothing to do with your status. Do as you wish but this is not the perfect way to interact with people especially who are helping you.

Comment: Thank you for the info sir.I will click the check mark.